# Where can I get historic prices for a commodity?

Tags: data-request, prices, cpi

Is there any way to get the price of a commodity over the last 100 years?

(Specifically, I'm looking for the price of toilet paper; I want to chart it and try to estimate the year where a piece of toilet paper will be worth more than $1.)

Comment: I would think that location would be an issue, as prices vary by region (eg, see the [Big Mac Index](http://www.economist.com/content/big-mac-index))

Answer (score 4):

Index Mundi has a lot of commodity data (present and historical) available to the public.

But I am not sure if you would find toilet paper on the list (lol) - it does not exactly fit the definition for a commodity:

*"a raw material or primary agricultural product that can be bought and sold, such as copper or coffee."*

http://www.indexmundi.com/commodities/