# Open data set for fair trade commodities in developing countries (any: bananas, sugar, wine/grapes)

Tags: data-request, economics, trade

Are there an open or freely available datasets on fairtrade goods (produce and products) in the developing countries? Looking for product, produce type, price data, location data and/or any type of local or national impact. Would prefer micro level impact (how it affects the community - outcomes soft (social capital) or hard (increase in wages). I would prefer raw data sets. I'm open to any commodity or country as long as the country is considered developing.

Comment: I think for "Fair Trade"-specific you'll have to go to the organizations that are certifying. They may provide the data behind [these reports](http://www.fairtrade.net/impact-and-research.html) if you ask nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You can find commodity trade information (by category) between countries in the UN ComTrade database

http://comtrade.un.org/

*The United Nations Commodity Trade Statistics Database (UN Comtrade) stores more than 1 billion trade data records from 1962. Over 140 reporter countries provide the United Nations Statistics Division with their annual international trade statistics detailed by commodities and partner countries. These data are subsequently transformed into the United Nations Statistics Division standard format with consistent coding and valuation using the UN/OECD CoprA internal processing system.*

The WTO also has datasets on trade between countries:

http://stat.wto.org/StatisticalProgram/WSDBStatProgramTechNotes.aspx?Language=E

The Food Agriculture Organization (FAO) of United Nations' statistical database ([FAOSTAT](https://www.fao.org/faostat/en/#data)) contains price data on wheat, tea, cereals, rice and sugar per country going back to 2002.

UPDATE: I answered a related question awhile back ago on datasets about commodities.

[Where can I get historic prices for a commodity?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3393/where-can-i-get-historic-prices-for-a-commodity/3399#3399)

Comment: I probably should have been more clear that I'm looking for Fair Trade data (it was lost a little in the paragraph).

Comment: I did get that, hence why I included the FAOSTAT database.